# Convert DateTime.Now result into array (24hours format)

Tags: c#

I am trying to send date & time to a remote data logger, I need to convert `DateTime.Now` into a Byte array.

For Example,

```
2015 will byte[0] = 20; 
byte[1] = 15;
byte[..] = 23 (11 pm)..
```

and so on so forth.

I am using C#, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
string logString = now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

byte[] logEntry;
int elements = logString.Length / 2;
logEntry = new byte[elements];

for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    logEntry[i] = Convert.ToByte(logString.Substring(i * 2, 2));
}

Console.WriteLine(logString);
Console.WriteLine();
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:00}", i, logEntry[i]);
}
```

Sample output:

```
20150820073306

0: 20
1: 15
2: 08
3: 20
4: 07
5: 33
6: 06
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, sorry,  I got busy with other project. I love simple answers.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure on your use case. If I can separate below statement from your query, my solution works to you.

***I need to convert Date Time.Now into Byte array***

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt);

// Covert to OA Date
double oadate = dt.ToOADate();
Console.WriteLine(oadate);

// Convert to byte array.
byte[] datebytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(oadate);
```

This can be converted back to `DateTime` with few lines of code.

```
double retvalue =  BitConverter.ToDouble(datebytes,0);    
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(retvalue));
```

Sample [code](http://double%20retvalue%20=%20%20BitConverter.ToDouble(datebytes,0);%20Console.WriteLine(retvalue);%20Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(retvalue));).